# Regex - Match the characters but not the forward slash

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am actually looking for the regex. Basically I want to match the below URL

```
/test/*/contact/*
```

My inputs are something like this

```
/test/1234/contact/abcd  ----   This is correct
/test/abcd/1234/contact/abcd --- This should show not match
```

I tried the regex as

```
\/test\/\S+\/contact\/\S+
```

By using the above exp it is showing both are correct. can someone help me how to exclude the forward slash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\S` pattern matches `/`. You should rely on `[^\/]` negated character class and use anchors:

```
^\/test\/[^\/]+\/contact\/[^\/]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0mlhX5/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\/test\/` - `/test/`
- `[^\/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `\/contact\/` - `/contact/`
- `[^\/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `$`  - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

`\S` means "Anything that isn't `\s`".

`\s` means "whitespaces". It equals to: [\r\n\t\f\v ]

- **\r** - carriage return
- **\n** - newline
- **\t** - tab
- **\f** - form-feed character (something like "next page")
- **\v** - vertical space
- - simple whitespace

Because of that, `\S` includes + `/`. To achieve what you want, you can either do something like "anything but spaces or slashes" (that would be: `[^\/\s]*`) or specify the characters you accept (for example, for alphanumeric and -_ it would be: `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*`).

If you have any question feel free to ask and I'll further explain